# MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING

Tags: firefox, ssl

I updated Firefox to version 67.0, and after the customary fights like getting the tabs on the right spot, I found I couldn't connect to `stackoverflow` anymore (or to [the redhat bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1343202)). I get

```
MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING
```

and that dialog doesn't let me ignore that problem like other certificate issues. I never experienced the problem with previous FF versions. From [this article](https://lichess.org/forum/lichess-feedback/problem-to-access-lichess-with-mozilla-firefox#4), I found I could disable `security.ssl.enable_ocsp_must_staple` (i.e. set to `false`).

I read that this is a Linux specific problem. Can anyone enlighten me what it means? And why this occurs so (seemingly) infrequently?

Comment: See [A required TLS feature is missing. Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_REQUIRED_TLS_FEATURE_MISSING
Ask](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385589/a-required-tls-feature-is-missing-error-code-mozilla-pkix-error-required-tls-f) on stackexchange Meta.

Comment: Cheers, Steffen! Seems a hot topic, not only here, but on several other sites almost simultaneously. Still looking for a (readable) reference about the 'mechanics'.